# How can I connect a repeating content to my VC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

How do I get this checkTest which is added through a UIView into my TableView Cell ? I've already subclassed my VC and added the outlet in that class, and also setting the prototype cell to that sub class.
This is my code of VC :

```
 class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var checkTest: BEMCheckBox!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.addSubview(checkTest)
    }

    }
```

[image: Here is the linked imag]

Comment: Show us how you've created your TableView cell. If you've used a prototype cell, then your approach will not work. As Daniel Legler says, you will need to subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: Also, your code adds new instances of BEMCheckBox to the same cell repeatedly. This isn't the right place to be adding subviews.

Comment: Since you appear to be using Interface Builder, the best place to add subviews would be in the storyboard that defines the cell. What are you connecting the `checkBox` outlet to?

Comment: @jlehr in my subclass as : `class subOfMain:ReminderTableViewController{ @IBOutlet weak var checkTest: BEMCheckBox! }`

Comment: It's an `IBOutlet`, so what are you trying to connect it to in Interface Builder? Please update your question rather than adding comments. If you don't provide a clear problem statement, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @S.Verma You need to create a custom cell subclassing UITableViewCell and connect your outlets to the custom cell instead of connecting it to the view controller or table view controller.

Comment: @jlehr I've edited my question

Comment: @LeoDabus I've edited my question

Comment: `class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var checkTest: BEMCheckBox!
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus can I directly add `subView` ? like in my edited code ?

Comment: You can access your cell's checkTest  outlet in your tableview controller. the setSelected method is added automatically when you subclass a UITableViewCell. If you would like to customize your cell you can     `override func didMoveToSuperview()`

Comment: @LeoDabus so I directly call `self.view.addSubview(checkTest)` in my `ViewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: You need to select your cell in Xcode and change from UITableViewCell to CustomCell in your inspector

Comment: @LeoDabus yes I've already done that. But where do I add the subView because in the VC class it is not accepting `checkTest`

Comment: What view? UITableViewCell is a UIView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138148/discussion-between-s-verma-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype. Add the outlets to that class and connect them. Now when you configure the cell you can access the outlets.